# How to change easily a TextBox to a Watermark TextBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, watermark

What's the simplest way to change this TextBox code to a watermark TextBox?

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="txtBoxAddress" Width="200" GotKeyboardFocus="TxtBoxAddress_GotKeyboardFocus" Text="" KeyUp="TxtBoxAddress_KeyUp"></TextBox>
```

Comment: I saw this post, but it was to much to read for this little change

Comment: Maby I'm not lazy, but the deadline is near?

Comment: *Maby I'm not lazy, but the deadline is near?*... I very much doubt that the deadline is so near that you don't have time to copy and paste a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option one would be to [use a background image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613590(v=vs.110).aspx) as described in the MSDN. If you want to use bindings this will probably be the best way.

**XAML**

```
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="myTextBox" TextChanged="OnTextBoxTextChanged" Width="200">
      <TextBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="TextBoxBackground.gif" AlignmentX="Left" Stretch="None" />
      </TextBox.Background>
    </TextBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace SDKSample
{
    public partial class TextBoxBackgroundExample : Page
    {

        void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (myTextBox.Text == "")
            {
                // Create an ImageBrush.
                ImageBrush textImageBrush = new ImageBrush();
                textImageBrush.ImageSource =
                    new BitmapImage(
                        new Uri(@"TextBoxBackground.gif", UriKind.Relative)
                    );
                textImageBrush.AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left;
                textImageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.None;
                // Use the brush to paint the button's background.
                myTextBox.Background = textImageBrush;

            }
            else
            {

                myTextBox.Background = null;
            }

        }

    }
```

Or you could use a BooleanToVisibilityConverter as described in [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26977/A-WatermarkTextBox-in-lines-of-XAML) .